# How to calculate the length of the next string that is going to be printed in Python?

Tags: python, string, console-application, string-length

I am trying to create a delay based on the length of a string. But the delay has to happen before the string is printed in the console. The goal is to add a bit of realism to an adventure game.

This is the current code I have come up with. I know it isn't right, but this is the first week I've been using Python.

```
import time

def calculate_text_speed(delay):
        delay = text.len() / 20

def start_game():
    calculate_text_speed(delay)
    
    time.sleep(calculate_text_speed.delay)
    print("Test message.")
```

Should I create a list with dialogues to calculate the the strings beforehand? This will probably decrease the readability of the code, right?

Comment: i believe you have to use `return delay` in the `calculate_text_speed(delay):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you mean by not declaring text?

```
def print_with_delay(text):
    time.sleep(len(text) / 20)
    print(text)

print_with_delay("Some very exciting things are happening....")
```

**Original answer:**
You can create very readable code without generating the text list ahead of time.

The main issue is you are passing the wrong thing to calculate_text_speed.  Try this.

```
import time

text = "Some very exciting things are happening...."

#pass text to the calculate_text_speed function
def calculate_text_speed(text):
    return len(text) / 20

time.sleep(calculate_text_speed(text))
print(text)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, but is it also possible to calculate a string without declaring it? Like print("Test message.") < calculate this string. Or am I thinking too hard?

Comment: @Tim You dont want to declare it, but how would you keep track of something that is not declared? Or maybe im getting you wrong. If you dont declare `text`, then it would be undefined, and how will they know what the message is, you have to have the message somewhere right?

Comment: See the updated answer.  Is that what you mean by not declaring text?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. You completely understand me. Sorry if you had any difficulties with understanding my problem earlier. Next time I will provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to return something from the first function, in your case it is:

In python for string length is len(text) not text.len()

```
return (len(text)() / 20)
```

then the function would look like this:

```
def calculate_text_speed(text):
        return (len(text) / 20)
```

Now to calculate text length,
you can pass the text variable globally or locally. I do now what you would want. I assume that you want it locally so in this case your second function would lok like:

```
def start_game(text):
    time.sleep(calculate_text_speed(text))
    print("Test message.")
```

**if for you want the text variable globally defined, then:**

```
text = "something"

def calculate_text_speed():
        return (len(text) / 20)

def start_game():
    time.sleep(calculate_text_speed())
    print("Test message.")

start_game()
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. The problem is, if I have 100 lines of text that might be displayed by the computer via the print() method, I need to declare all the strings that are going to be displayed.

Comment: from where the string are coming ?? what did you mean actually ?